# Check Element not in array in java script?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hi I am New to JS i trying below code

```
a=[0,1,3]
if (2 in a){ console.log(a)}
```

in above code i am checking element is available are not. but in above case 2 is not in array but condition show true why?

i know we can check condition like this a.includes(2) 
why in above case showing true?

Thanks Advance.

Comment: [_"The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). Here, the key "2" is a property of this Array (it's the index of the value "3")

Comment: 0xc14m1z's answer is correct - what you need to use is `a.indexOf(2) !== -1` for checking if `2` is in `a`.  be careful using `.includes()`, it's not supported in IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Becase the `in` operator checks whether a property is defined in an object.

The array indexes are the "properties" of the array objects, thus, the 2 property is the index 2, which contains the value 3.